# is there any method that can remove fragment's all data by navigate another fragment on Navigation drawer activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to remove all data of **Home** Fragment while navigation to **Gallery** Fragment in **Navigation Drawer activity**.

My Problem is that I have to delete some value in **gallery fragment** but that value is loaded in **home fragment**. By deleting value on **Gallery Fragment** *on a null object reference* error comes in **Home Fragment**.
So my question is that how I can remove loaded data from Home Fragment while navigation to Gallery Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard to answer without knowing what exactly you use for Navigation

If you don't use something like MVVM, you probably should. Navigation Component is also good.

If you are a beginner, the easiest option is to edit the method that gets called when navigating away and just set your variables to null (if within the same Fragment).

Lifecycle methods like onStop() get called in other cases too so I wouldn't use those.

If the Fragment that needs stuff deleted isn't the one executing the code, you should probably have the data outside of a Fragment (e.g. Repository, you can delete the data from it anywhere)